# Eclipse RCP: Height of a search text in the toolbar in Eclipse 4.6

Tags: java, user-interface, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse 3.8 RCP application that runs on the Eclipse 4.4 platform using 
the [compatibility layer](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/february/article3.php#compatibiliylayer).
In the toolbar there is a search text which looks like this:

[image: toolbar 4.4]

But when I run the application on Eclipse 4.6 it looks like this:

[image: toolbar 4.6]

The search text is added via the following extension point in the `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
<menuContribution
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.command2">
    <toolbar id="search.toolbar">
    <control 
        class="app.SearchText"
        id="app.SearchText">
    </control>
    </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
</extension>
```

The `SearchText` class looks like this:

```
public class SearchText extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

// ...

@Override
protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    log.trace("create search text control");
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.numColumns = 2;
    layout.horizontalSpacing = 5;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 5;
    layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    composite.setLayout(layout);
    text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH);
    // ...
    return composite;
}

// ...
```

I played with the layout parameters but with no success and I have no idea how
this could be fixed. Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported a bug a while ago: [main toolbar control contributions is cut off](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471326)

Here is a workaround:

The class should extend `ControlContribution` instead of `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution`.

In the `YourApplicationNameActionBarAdvisor.fillCoolBar()` (replace the YourApplicationName) add: `toolbar.add(new SearchText());`

Here the print screens of the reported bug, must be the same issue.

**Test with Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)**
[image: Test with Eclipse Luna (4.4.2)]

**Test with Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)**
[image: Test with Eclipse Mars (4.5.0)]

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I confirm that this works. However, I would like to have the search text on the right side of the toolbar. Is there a way how to do this with your workaround? Thanks again.

Comment: took a short look but didn't find a solution, maybe search the web.

Comment: @Michael did you figure out to add to right side of toolbar? Please let me know if you, in a similar situation right now.

Comment: @Null Pointer No, we still are running the application on Eclipse 4.4 (did not tried again). If you find a solution it would be great if you could post it here. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael , thanks for the update. We are using Eclipse 4.3, couldn't make it working with org.eclipse.ui.trim.command2 . I believe it's because of "Quick Access" box on the platform (even if we hide that it didn't work). Because, it worked with 3.x version of the eclipse platform. Will keep you posted if I find solution, please do the same from your end as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) the following workaround posted on [this issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471313) worked for me:

```
public class MyWorkbenchWindowControlContribution extends
    WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {

  @Override
  protected Control createControl(Composite parent) {
    parent.getParent().setRedraw(true);
    ....
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isDynamic() {
    return true;
  }
  ...
```